# Spring Boot default resource locations not finding static files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm running a local Spring Boot app that builds to a .jar file and deploys to AWS. I am having trouble getting the app to resolve references to embedded static files. I understand that Spring Boot defaults to the following resource directories:

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" }
```

I have built my css directory structure accordingly:

```
/src/main/resources/static/css/styles.css
```

In my Thymeleaf template, I am attempting to reference the file as follows (have tried with and without the leading slash):

```
<link th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I set a breakpoint in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration.getResourceLocations()` and start the app, I can see that the static resource locations are indeed the defaults Spring provides.

When I attempt to hit the file directly at "http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css", the request is routed through my default controller with root mapping `@GetMapping()`, and the site home page is loaded. As a test, I temporarily changed that mapping to "/home" and I *was* able to hit the css file directly, but the styles still don't get applied when viewing a pages in a browser.

I have a tried many solutions found on SO and elsewhere (including https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources). I have tried  implementing my own `@Configuration`/`@EnableWebMvc` class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and overrides the `addResourceHandlers()` method. I have tried overriding the resource paths from `application-local.yml`, as well. I have tried every conceivable path combination, root-relative, page-relative, etc with and without "webjars", but nothing working for me. Would appreciate a gentle nudge or violent kick in the right direction.

[EDIT] I have additionally tried to debug through through `PathResourceResolver` but the only resource request that it ever acknowledges is favicon.ico. The request for my css file never makes it way into `PathResourceResolver` . Shouldn't requests for any resource under one of the default resource paths come through here?

Comment: The main issue is you have a default controller which acts as a catch all. Also don't use `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables the Spring Boot defaults and thus as well the static resource resolution.